# Using Capybara and Rspec, how do I get more verbose logging?

Tags: ruby, rspec, selenium-webdriver, capybara

Currently my Capybara/Selenium/RSpec script runs with no output. It simply sit there and waits until all scenarios have finished. I want more verbose output.

To start, I want a log at the beginning of each scenario, so that I know which scenarios are running.

Then I want the result of each scenario to be logged, pass or fail.

Can I do this manually with before/after hooks? Is there an option I can pass to the "rspec" command? Or maybe some other solution?

Comment: Check out the rspec [command line](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line) docs.  It sounds like you are looking for the `--format documentation` option.

Comment: I'll accept that if it's the only answer. I'd also like to see if there are before/after hooks or some other solution.

Comment: I would add logger into your tests so that you could monitor progress of run. http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#class-Logger-label-Description

Comment: Yes this is what I need to find out which test rspec is crashing on! "Webpack binstubs not found" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614106/error-running-rspec-webpack-binstubs-not-found