# Error running rspec in window: Webpack binstubs not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, windows, webpack, rspec

When I run `rspec` I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\catalyst_research>rspec

Randomized with seed 41345
FFFFFFF............................FFFFFFFC:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webpacker-2.0/lib/tasks/installers.rake:1: warning: already initialized constant INSTALLERS
C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webpacker-2.0/lib/tasks/installers.rake:1: warning: previous definition of INSTALLERS was here
C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webpacker-2.0/lib/tasks/webpacker/install.rake:1: warning: already initialized constant WEBPACKER_APP_TEMPLATE_PATH
C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webpacker-2.0/lib/tasks/webpacker/install.rake:1: warning: previous definition of WEBPACKER_APP_TEMPLATE_PATH was here
C:/Users/Chloe/workspace/catalyst_research/lib/tasks/test.rake:6: warning: already initialized constant DRIVERS
C:/Users/Chloe/workspace/catalyst_research/lib/tasks/test.rake:6: warning: previous definition of DRIVERS was here
Webpack binstubs not found.
Make sure the bin directory or binstubs are not included in .gitignore
Exiting!
```

I do have `bin/webpack`

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\catalyst_research>ls bin/webpack
bin/webpack
```

I did successfully run `npm install` (with some warnings)

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\catalyst_research>npm install
npm WARN rollback Rolling back tar-pack@3.4.0 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\catalyst_research\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

up to date in 34.749s
```

`rails test` runs nothing:

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\catalyst_research>rails test
...
0 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

`rake test` gives the same error above. `grep webpack .gitignore` returns nothing. I'm not very familiar with RSpec. I haven't used it in 5 years. I prefer Minitest because of these incompatibility problems.

- Rails 5.0.6,
- RSpec 3.7,
- Yarn 1.5.1,
- NPM 5.6.0,
- Node 9.10.1,
- Windows 8.1,
- Ruby 2.4.3,
- WebPack ~>2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had renamed `/bin/webpack-dev-server` to `bin/webpack-dev-server.rb` because it was a Ruby file and wasn't launching in Foreman. When I renamed it back RSpec started working again.